# Table View Controller default methods in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using xcode 5 , I start a new single page project . I delete the default view controller and replace it with a tableviewcontroller in the storyboard . I create an objective c file ( a view controller) for this table view controller and link the class to the storyboard . I cannot see the default methods that should appear for a table view controller . Is there an alternate approach to get these methods

Comment: If you know you have a `UITableViewController` class in your storyboard, why did you create your new file as a `UIViewController`? This would avoid your issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The default template for table view controller implements the methods for the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. You can find which methods you need to implement [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate).

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to change your class to be a `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController` in your header file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController
```

Or set up your `UIViewController` to conform to the table view data source and delegate:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

This will make it so that the "default" methods will auto-complete as you start typing them in. Check the documentation to see which methods are required or optional and fill in as needed.

[UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)
[UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)

Don't forget to hook up your table view in your storyboard to the delegate and data source.

Comment: When I created the view controllers I made them inherit it from a UITable . I assume that should populate the methods dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake , was creating a mac OSX objective C file instead of a IOS objective C file .